# Does partitioning external hard drive sacrifice performance

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have a Mac Mini server with 2 external 5TB hard drives (2.5") attached.  One drive has media for serving over the network, the other drive is for Time Machine backups.

My question is if I replace these two drives with a single desktop 10TB drive and partition them to match my current setup, will I see a performance hit?  I can't imagine it would be as fast if I were streaming media over the network while another computer was backing up to the server.

Comment: Depends on where the bottleneck is. Is your network speed faster than the single drive? Is the drive interface faster than the drive (USB2, USB3, etc.) Assuming your network is running at gigabit speed, you’ll never move more than 120MBps through the Mac from computers on the network and if the hard drive is faster than that it might not make a difference. That’s a highly simplified view, physical heads still have to seek the data it is looking for, so thrashing is a problem no matter what. Two drives are always going to provide better performance than one. The question is if you’ll notice.

Comment: @appleoddity Thanks!  It's a gigabit network and the drives are connected via USB 3.0.  Perhaps I wouldn't even notice but if two drives are better I will stick with it.